# GTK# TreeView -- never receives events?

Tags: drag-and-drop, treeview, gtk#

I find that on a GTK# 2.12 TreeView, I do not receive the appropriate events. My setup is as follows:

```
        var tv = Handle.TreeView;
        var targets = new[] { new Gtk.TargetEntry(TargetType, Gtk.TargetFlags.App, 0) };
        Gtk.Drag.SourceSet(tv, Gdk.ModifierType.Button1Mask, targets, Gdk.DragAction.Move);
        Gtk.Drag.DestSet(tv, Gtk.DestDefaults.All, targets, Gdk.DragAction.Move);
```

I receive DragBegin, and on drop, I get DragFailed and then DragEnd. Never do DragMotion, DragDataGet, or DragDataReceived get called. Is there something I need to do to cause GTK# to raise these events?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really worked with Drag&Drop, but there is a [Drag&Drop tutorial for plain Gtk+](https://wiki.gnome.org/Newcomers/DragNDropTutorial) (porting should be more or less simple). Also, check [Mono's docs about Gtk#'s Gtk.Drag](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3AGtk.Drag).